# Export Google Workspace data to LimaCharlie

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to export [Google Workspace](https://admin.google.com) data to [LimaCharlie](https://limacharlie.io).

This is what I have managed to do so far:

1. Create a Google Cloud project at console.cloud.google.com named "Workspace-To-LimaCharlie".
2. Enabled BigQuery Export at admin.google.com under `Reporting -> BigQuery Export` to the project "Workspace-To-LimaCharlie".

Now I am in the Analytics Hub and I do not know what to click to make it send its data to LimaCharlie.

[image]

I see in LimaCharlie that I got two diffrent methods of ingesting Google logs:

- Events through a GCP Pubsub topic
- Google Cloud Storage

**LimaCharlie Events through a GCP Pubsub topic**

[image]

**LimaCharlie Google Cloud Storage**

[image]